# Let's Encrypt in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have a windows server that uses tomcat to serve an application. I need to setup SSL on it. I have followed just about every resources I could find and I cannot figure it out.

I generated local `.keystore` file using keygen and updated the server.xml file in my another system and SSL works on it but when using Let's Encrypt, I am using https://www.sslforfree.com/ to generate the files. I have ca_bundle.crt , certificate.crt and private.key.

How do I change these 3 files to a .keystore file?

Comment: i have this exact question.

Answer (score -1):

install apr

```
apt-get install libapr1 libtcnative-1 libapr1-dev
sudo ln -sv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcnative-1.so /usr/lib/
```

copy your files to /usr/local/ssl

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/ssl
sudo mv ca_bundle.crt /usr/local/ssl/
sudo mv certificate.crt /usr/local/ssl/
sudo mv private.key /usr/local/ssl/
```

then modify your tomcat server.xml and maybe remove the HTTP connector

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />

<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
       port="443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       SSLCertificateChainFile="/usr/local/ssl/ca_bundle.crt"
       SSLCertificateFile="/usr/local/ssl/certificate.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="/usr/local/ssl/private.key"
       SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>
```

Comment: note: if you wanna run on 443, tomcat will need to run as root, another can of worms.